# Can't show text on image with a hyperlink

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to show text on image in html, and make the image a hyper link. Without the hyper link, it works:

[image: without_hyper]
("`Description . . .`" is the text I want to show)

Here's the html code for this:

```
<div>
    <img u="image" src="img/photography/003.jpg"/>
    <h2><span>Description . . .</span></h2>
</div>
```

But when I make the image a hyper link to some website, the text disappears:

```
<div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><img u="image" src="img/photography/003.jpg"/></a>
    <h2><span>Description . . .</span></h2>
</div>
```

[image: without_hyper]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (make the text absolute positioned)

```
<div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><img u="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRrs8.png"/></a>
    <h2 style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 10px;"><span>hghghghghg . . .</span></h2>
</div>
```